# stream music headlessly through ssh rasberry-pi

Tags: command-line, ssh

I have a raspberry pi and I want to run certain things (programs or stream music) headlessly through ssh. I am already setup via ssh to my pi from my Mac.. I would like to my pi to play music... please help sorry if the question isn't worded correctly.

Comment: Possible:  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=10028

Comment: File "server.address:port/directory" not found. This is the error I'm getting

Comment: That means, you put in the information for where your music is stored that you want to stream.  You have to replace that with your information.  It is only a suggestion.

Comment: I'm not very smart when it comes to all of this. My accumulative experience is only a few days here and there. I'm not sure I understand your answer.

Comment: First of all, are you using Ubuntu as an OS at all?  If not, this should be asked on another site here at [Stack Exchange] (https://stackexchange.com/).  This probably is more of a question that should be for https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ since you want to stream through the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output that you recieve when you type in the following command: `uname -a` and `lsb_release -a`